# Get URL parameters in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, get

I need to get the ID parameter in a URL, for example I have

```
http://apps/inventory/others.aspx?ID=8678
```

How do I extract the `8678`, I've looked at the method of the Object `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` but I haven't found anything. Could that be possible with a simple substring? The URL is always the same and there is always one GET parameter,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print ExtractAfter("http://apps/inventory/others.aspx?ID=8678", "ID=")
    Debug.Print ExtractAfter("http://apps/inventory/others.aspx?ID=867843", "ID=")

End Sub

Public Function ExtractAfter(strInput As String, strAfter As String) As String

    ExtractAfter = Mid(strInput, InStr(strInput, strAfter) + Len(strAfter))

End Function
```

This is what you get in the immediate window:

```
8678
867843
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, assuming you have the url in a variable `url`:

```
Debug.Print Mid(url, InStr(url, "ID=") + 3)
```

However, works only correct if the ID parameter is always present and always the only paramter, else you need some more sophisticated string handling.